# Use mongo operator $and in Phalcon\Mvc\Collection

Tags: php, mongodb, operators, phalcon, odm

im trying to use the operator $and of MongoDB applied to the Phalcon\Mvc\Collection as follow:

```
   $documents = Staff::find( $condition);
```

with array $**condition** having the "**role**" like this:

```
$condition["role"] = [
            "\$regex" => "$somevalue",  
            "\$and"=> [
                '$ne' => "admin" 
                ]     
            ];
```

and i get this error

> Can't canonicalize query: Bad Value: unknown operator: $and'

Please help me solve this. 
Is there any better way to apply multi conditions to this "**role**"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$and` is implicty used in mongo by default. Just `"$ne" => "admin"` should be enough i think.

> MongoDB provides an implicit AND operation when specifying a comma
>   separated list of expressions. Using an explicit AND with the $and
>   operator is necessary when the same field or operator has to be
>   specified in multiple expressions.